# Plotting time of day distribution in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have data in excel which lists several events as a time-of-day, in a single column for each day, like so:

```
1/1/2018    2/1/2018
10:23       00:23
14:53       13:14
16:01       14:19
23:01       16:01
            19:02
            20:00
            21:00
            22:23
```

I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to create a chart which would plot an X axis of the dates and a Y axis of the time of day, from 00:00 to 23:59, and have a distribution of dots for each of the dates, in order to visually show whether events tend to happen more often at certain hours. It should look like this:

[image: Example of chart]

I don't know if this is easy to accomplish in Excel (it should be...) Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been struggling with "Insert X Y Scatter Chart" for the last 45 minutes.

Comment: If the next column doesn't have the same number of entries, how do you want to match them up?  Can you edit the question to show both columns side-by-side (uses spaces to fake columns), and then give an example of how you want the results to look?

Comment: @Ian, you need some basic changes. U must create one column for Date & Other for Time, then plot XY graph, and format one for Date & Other for Time. While doing this select Number and from Category select Date/Time & other parameters. ☺

Answer (score 1):

You can use Line with Marker chart to get the result.

1. Based on the data source insert a Line with Marker chart and go to Chart Tool- Data- Select Data, change the data as shown in the following picture:
   [image]
2. Change all Series from Solid line to No Line:
   [image]
3. Change Axis options as shown in the following picture:
   [image]

Then you will get the result you want.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed steps. However, on MacOS the interface is very different and although some of the fields are similarly named, I couldn't reproduce your steps. Please have a look at the MacOS dialog window and see if you can figure out how it should be done. Thanks again for your time. https://imgur.com/fZEsUSH

Comment: It took me a little while to work out how to replicate this in Mac (see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CKWH.png)).  Without pre-selecting the data I did Insert -> Chart (Line with Markers).  Then Select Data.  I set the Chart data range to the section of data (excluding date header, eg `A2:B9`), then Switch Row/Column.  Finally add the Horizontal axis labels (this updates the data range to `A1:B9`) and that's it.  It looks like you need to change the line to `none` for each series individually.

Comment: I can't replicate this behavior here after several tries following your steps & screen grab closely. (1) Insert Chart without selecting the data. (2) Choose Select Data. (3) Set "Chart data range" to the entire table w/o the headers — this results in 2 lines in the "Legend entries" section which look like "6:23 8:20 8:47..." (4) Switch Row/Column — this results in several "Legend entries", each of them showing a time value (not "Series1" etc). (5) Define "Horizontal axis labels" to be the headers row — this results in "Chart Data Range is too complex to be displayed". cf. youtu.be/DoGSeNcbJEs

Comment: Wow.  That data set behaves differently.  Excel must see a pattern.  It splits the column into 2: `Name` is `B2:B8` and `Y values` is `B9:B14`.  You might need to create the data series' manually.  Which is tedious.  From the Select Data step, don't use the Chart data range.  Instead click the `+` below the Legend entries, set the Y values to the row (first series, `A2:C2`) and the horizontal axis to the labels (`A1:C1`).  Then create another series, Y values `A3:C3`, you can skip the labels.  Repeat for every row, ensuring they are all the same width (regardless of blank cells).

Comment: Thank you, you are correct. It **does** work (sorta) and it **is** pretty tedious to set up. Also, the labels on the vertical axis can't be defined and it seems impossible to define "no line" as a whole, you have to do it for every data row. I thought this would be a simple problem... But this is one more issue with non-feature-parity with Excel for Mac when dealing with more advanced requirements. Anyway, thank you very much for your time and effort. I think it will actually be quicker to just write a python script to plot data from a csv file :)